# Can I activate a physical copy of Team fortress 2 if I already have it in my library?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I am planning to buy a physical copy of tf2 but I already have TF2 on Steam. Is there any way to transfer it to the physical one?

Comment: why would you want to buy a free game

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Why would you buy a physical game that is already available in your library?  If you want to become a premium user, just buy something from the Mann Co. Store.

Comment: @Riftcaster - Free to play has some restrictions over a premium account, like reduced backpack space and so on. As JAL states though, simply buying something from the TF2 store is enough to make your account premium

Comment: are you trying to get something extra from the physical copy? such as the proof of purchase hat or a premium account?

Comment: I am using someone else's account and computer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your copy of TF2 in your library is currently 'Free-to-play', and you're simply wanting to upgrade it to a Premium account, I would recommend against purchasing a physical copy of the game (for the purposes of activating TF2). According to the [Team Fortress 2 FAQ](http://www.teamfortress.com/freetoplay/faq.php):

> #### Q. How do I convert my free account to a premium account?
>
> Make any purchase of any amount in the in-game Mann Co. store.
>
> #### Q. Will I need a credit card to play?
>
> No. However, to make purchases from the in-game Mann Co. Store you will need to use [one of our accepted payment methods](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8360-WEJC-2625#acceptedforms).
>
> #### Q. What is the Mann Co. Store?
>
> The finest virtual item store in the world, easily accessible from within the TF2 game client.

Whilst the option above is the easiest & most common way to get a Premium account so long as you have a Credit/Debit card, there are other ways to do so which don't require a card (and are not listed on the FAQ):

- A friend can gift you an [**Upgrade to Premium Gift**](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Upgrade_to_Premium_Gift) item, which you then activate from within your TF2 Backpack to become premium.
- In some countries you can purchase a 'Steam Wallet' recharge card at a local retail store, and use this money to then purchase an item on the Mann Co. store.

---

Otherwise, if you're after the '[Proof of Purchase](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Proof_of_Purchase)' hat, then yes, you can either activate a retail copy of the game or a gifted version of the game (note that a gifted copy of the game on Steam is different from the 'Upgrade to Premium' TF2 item):

> This hat is given to players who purchased Team Fortress 2 before the Über Update on June 23, 2011, those who receive a gift of the game, and those who activate a retail copy of the game, such as purchasing the Orange Box.